# Access column value of previous output

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I am starting to work with PyQGIS. I used the Modellbuilder in QGIS, exported to Python and changed some lines to make it work again.
Everything is working but one Line. (I tested it by manually setting the correct value there.)

I try to kinda filter a layer to the objects i want.
Of those objects (all on the same location/coordinates) i want to grab the X and Y coordinates (saved in columns "X" (#10) and "Y" (#11)) and use them as the START_POINT of shortest path function.

```
    # NVT Objekt
    alg_params = {
        'EXPRESSION': '\"Lokationstyp\" = \'NVT\'\r\nAND\r\nto_int(\"Lokationsnummer\") = @NVtNummereinfachzB0011 ',
        'INPUT': 'standortliste_4796c771_8b3f_4a47_9958_33aeb9d97c85',
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['NvtObjekt'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    ...

    # Kürzester Weg (Punkt zu Layer)
    alg_params = {
        'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,  # Beide Richtungen
        'DEFAULT_SPEED': 50,
        'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
        'END_POINTS': outputs['StandortlisteNachRohrverbandFilternNachPositionExtrahieren']['OUTPUT'],
        'INPUT': outputs['Rohr_rohrverbandNachNvtUndRohrverbandFilternNachAusdruckExtrahieren']['OUTPUT'],
        'SPEED_FIELD': '',
        'START_POINT': QgsExpression(' @NVT_Objekt_OUTPUT_maxx || \',\' ||  @NVT_Objekt_OUTPUT_maxy \r\n||\r\n\' [EPSG:25832]\'').evaluate(),
        'STRATEGY': 0,  # Kürzester
        'TOLERANCE': 0.05,
        'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
        'VALUE_BOTH': '',
        'VALUE_FORWARD': '',
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['KrzesterWegPunktZuLayer'] = processing.run('native:shortestpathpointtolayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

...
```

I am trying to find a working expression for START_POINT now for some time and everything i try fails. Most of the time i get the "str object has no attribute ..."-error while trying to access outputs['NvtObjekt']['OUTPUT']['X'] or outputs['NvtObjekt']['OUTPUT'].maximumValue(10).

Comment: Found my solution in trying this:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361353/store-result-of-a-processing-algorithm-as-a-layer-in-qgis-python-script

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can not easily access the output of a function and keep on working with it as a layer. You have to save the output as a layer first.

My solution looks like that now:

```
                alg_params = {
                    'EXPRESSION': '\"Lokationstyp\" = \'NVT\'\r\nAND\r\nto_int(\"Lokationsnummer\") = ' + str(nvt_loop_count) ,
                    'INPUT': parameters['standortliste'],
                    ##'OUTPUT': parameters['Nvt']
                    'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
                }
                outputs['NvtObjekt'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
                nvtobjektlayer= context.takeResultLayer(outputs['NvtObjekt']["OUTPUT"])
...
                alg_params = {
                    'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,  # Beide Richtungen
                    'DEFAULT_SPEED': 50,
                    'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
                    'END_POINTS': outputs['StandortlisteNachRohrverbandFilternNachPositionExtrahieren']['OUTPUT'],
                    'INPUT': outputs['Rohr_rohrverbandNachNvtUndRohrverbandFilternNachAusdruckExtrahieren']['OUTPUT'],
                    'SPEED_FIELD': '',
                    ##'START_POINT': '476813.633595,5524575.219635 [EPSG:25832]',
                    ##'START_POINT': str(context.takeResultLayer(outputs['NvtObjekt']['OUTPUT']).maximumValue(10)) + ' || \',\' || ' + str(context.takeResultLayer(outputs['NvtObjekt']['OUTPUT']).maximumValue(11)) + ' \r\n||\r\n\' [EPSG:25832]\'',
                    'START_POINT': str(nvtobjektlayer.maximumValue(10)) + ',' + str(nvtobjektlayer.maximumValue(11)) + ' [EPSG:25832]',
                    'STRATEGY': 0,  # Kürzester
                    'TOLERANCE': 0.05,
                    'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
                    'VALUE_BOTH': '',
                    'VALUE_FORWARD': '',
                    'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
                }
                outputs['KrzesterWegPunktZuLayer'] = processing.run('native:shortestpathpointtolayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```